# Facebook Messenger Send Api - send to a big amount of users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a bot over Facebook which people are subscribing for sports updates.

I have 1,000 - 10,000 users I want to send out an update to.

Currently, in small scales like 20 messages , I would use a Facebook Batch request.

But, i'm not sure what would be the best way to send my messages in a large scale.

**My two options are:**

1. **Batch** - limited to 50 requests per batch request. 
   I don't really know if I should expect a delay in the execution of the request.
2. **Regular** calls - I will iterate through my receivers and send each of them a message separately. 
   I'm afraid Facebook might block me for thinking i'm spamming, or I will exceed the rate limits.

I have to say I was expecting a more generic method coming from Facebook since they are allowing users to subscribe for update through my bot, hence, I was expecting them to provide a guide on what are the best practices for sending the update users subscribed for.

Comment: First of all, in regard to API rate limits it doesn’t make a difference if you batch your requests or not. Secondly, I don’t think there’s any rate limits that apply at this point - if you have a legitimate use case to send messages to users, then that’s that, why would Facebook limit that in any way? // Batching the requests is nevertheless a good idea, because it reduces the number of HTTP requests you have to make when communicating with the API.

Comment: @CBroe this what I was thinking about, I was just wondering if there is something more specific for the messenger bots, since obviously, if Facebook approved us to allow users to subscribe, potentially, the amount of subscribed user could infinite, so they should allow us to do infinite amount of requests to maintain the communication with these users

Comment: Pretty sure that is the case, yes.

Comment: @AsafNevo היי אסף, איך התמודדת עם זה בסוף? :)

Comment: We use batch requests

Comment: @AsafNevo Hello, where can I see a basic example to send messages to multiple users with batch requests ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use [Facebook Messenger Broadcast API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/broadcast-messages) for this. This will broadcast your message to all user subscribed to the bot.

Caveats:

1. You have to apply for this permission. (pages_messaging and pages_messaging_subscriptions.Takes about 1-2 days, but
   can test on Admin/Test users of the app)
2. Each broadcast has to be a separate broadcast. (e.g. you can't send image and a text together, each has to be its own individual broadcast).
3. Have some kind of un-subscription option as well. FB user might think you are spamming even if you clearly say in the messages that your bot will send updates.
4. Use [custom labels](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/broadcast-messages/target-broadcasts) to create targetted sends. So you can either subdivide who you will send updates to about specific issues or just label people if they unsubscribe to your broadcast or not.

Basic workflow:

1. Get permission to broadcast.
2. Create message_creative_id via POST to endpoint
3. Use message_creative_id to POST a broadcast_messages
4. On a successful send you will get back broadcast_id

Comment: To the future readers: This method no longer works as Facebook has imposed severe restrictions over its API